# Smallest set of words contained in a number of documents

Tags: pca, dataset, natural-language

I have a collection of text documents. I would like to find the smallest set of words such that searching by those words allows discovering each document.

It is quite natural to describe this data as a matrix, where columns are unique words and rows give the number of times a word occurs in a given document.

What would be an efficient way of discovering the smallest set?

If I'm not mistaken, finding an exact solution requires testing all possible combinations. That is obviously too much asked even with a small amount of unique words. So how could I arrive at "good" solutions (set of words describes most variation) .. Something like PCA makes sense here?

Comment: Could you describe it in greater detail? Otherwise, the obvious answer is to calculate sets of words for each documents and then take their intersection.

Comment: @Tim I don't believe that, perhaps because we have different understandings of what "discovering each document" might mean. Consider two documents where one has words "A", "B", "C", "D", and the second has words "A", "B", "C", "E".  If I search for words contained in the set {"D","E"} I will both find a document and identify it, whereas the intersection of the two sets of words {"A", "B", "C"} has *three* elements, which is not minimal.  mmh: please explain what you mean by "allows discovering each document."

Comment: @whuber yes it won't be minimal, that's why I asked for a clarification. In a case like above picking arbitrary word of the set of common words would be "minimal" though not necessary the best solution depending on the details.

Comment: To avoid further propagating any confusion, I would recommend  *waiting* for that clarification before posting answers to any question you're unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

*There are many ways how this could be done and which exactly is the best depends on the details of your problem, that you didn't give us.*

- If you simply want to identify unique words per document or common words between documents, this needs treating documents as sets of words and calculating set intersection (common words) or difference (unique words). Since set can be implemented as a hash map, [those operations are quite cheap computationally](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).
- But are you sure you need to find the unique words? If you have large enough collection of documents, it can be as well the case that there is no unique words, or very few of them, so finding them would not make much sense. Much simpler solution might be to just code the word occurrences as [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) vectors and match them by encoding the query and finding the document with the most similar encoding. If you care about size of the data, this could be efficiently implemented as sparse vectors.
- More sophisticated approach could be to use a language model to encode the document as latent vectors and calculate the similarities in terms of the latent vectors rather than the raw one-hot encodings. If you care about *representing* the documents in the most compressed form, this might be one way of doing so.
- Finally, there are many out-of-the box solutions available (like [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/)) and starting with those is often a much better idea than re-inventing the wheel yourself.